# Why memory profiler doesn't show all the used memory?

Tags: c++, memory, valgrind, profiler, massif

When I am starting my application under valgrind with massif option I see 52.6 MiB peak usage.
[image]
But htop says the process took 875MB of RES memory.
[image]
[image]

The same behavior has heaptrack. Does anyone know why profiler doesn't report where 800+MB gone?

Comment: massif only measures heap usage ad not mapped memory (by default). Did you try `--pages-as-heap=yes`?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. You can submit this as answer. This is what I need.

Comment: Although your columns headers are somehow misaligned, it seems to show 875M virtual of which 812M is shared. Do you _want_ to count shared memory (such as mapped shared libraries) as "used"? That memory might have been used even without your process, and the ~63M difference looks about right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Massif by default measures only the heap managed by `malloc` and friends. It doesn't attempt to track pages mapped by other means (for example with `mmap`).

In order to account for all pages, one needs to run massif with `--pages-as-heap=yes`.

Source: [Massif manual](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html#ms-manual.not-measured).